# echo (echo "please wait, $i") >> cmds.txt in bash

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash script where it creates a text file with some commands which i will use to run. 
In between commands i want to place an echo message to be sent to the text file, how to acheieve this?

```
c=0;
for i in `cat`; do
echo "bash stopservers.sh $i" >> cmds.txt;
echo  (echo "please wait, stopping Managed server $i") >> cmds.txt
echo "sleep  10" >>cmds.txt
c=$((c+1));
done <  list.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: i have tried this      
echo " echo "please wait, stopping Managed server $i" ">> cmds.txt" 

 but getting the below output 

echo please wait, stopping Managed server 123" ----- missing the quotes

Comment: `echo " echo \"please wait, stopping Managed server $i\" ">> cmds.txt` will help :-)

Comment: [Do not use a `for` loop and `cat` to read the contents of a file; use `read` and a `while` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Replace your `echo  (echo "please wait, stopping Managed server $i") >> cmds.txt` statement with

```
echo 'echo "please wait, stopping Managed server '$i'"' >> cmds.txt
```

Comment: Fails if the value of `$i` contains a double quote (for example).

Answer (score 2):

First, use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop to ensure you handle each line accurately.

Using `printf` simplifies the quoting; the `%q` format ensures `$line` is properly quoted for use in a command line.

You can redirect the entire loop to `cmds.txt`, instead of doing it line-by-line in the body.

```
c=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf 'bash stopservers.sh %q\n' "$line"
  printf 'printf %q %q\n' '%s\n' "Please wait, stopping managed server $line"
  printf 'sleep 10\n'
  c=$((c+1))
done < list.txt >> cmds.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Generating `bash` code from `bash` or `sh` is tough.

- If you are generating `bash` code from `bash`, you can use `printf %q` as follows:

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line; do
      printf 'bash stopservers.sh %q\n' "$line"
      printf 'printf %q %q\n' '%s\n' "Please wait, stopping managed server $line"
      printf 'sleep 10\n'
  done <servers_list.txt >cmds.txt
  ```
- If you are generating `bash` code from `sh`, you can use the following:

  ```
  q() {
      prefix=''
      for p in "$@" ; do
          printf "$prefix"\'
          printf %s "$p" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"
          printf \'
          prefix=' '
      done
  }

  while IFS= read -r line; do
      printf '%s\n' "$(q bash stopservers.sh "$line"                                )"
      printf '%s\n' "$(q printf '%s\n' "Please wait, stopping managed server $line" )"
      printf '%s\n' "$(q sleep 10                                                   )"
  done <servers_list.txt >cmds.txt
  ```

In bothe cases, there are no restrictions on what `$i` can contain; the value will be properly escaped.

Comment: I think this is overly complicated for `bash`, which already provides a `%q` format for ensuring properly quoted strings.

Comment: @chepner, That's awesome! I didn't know about `%q`! Added a `%q` solution (which I've copied to your answer since yours was broken).